# Is there a way to completely disable Spaces in El Capitan?

Tags: mission-control, macos, spaces

Is there a way to completely disable Spaces in El Capitan without turning off Mission Control, Dashboard, etc.?
If not, is there a way to disable drag to space?

I'm using Cinch and I find it quite annoying to be offered space switching when dragging the window to the top of the screen just to maximize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found that if head to mission control and uncheck 'displays have different spaces', then logout/login you should be sweet. Worked for me anyways.